# Leerzeichen vor einem Auslassungsdreipunkt

Tags: usage, spelling, literature

**TLDR**

Muss vor einen Auslassungsdreipunkt - … - , der eine Pause oder Unterbrechung anzeigt, immer ein (volles) Leerzeichen oder kann dichterische Freiheit darauf verzichten?

---

Ich hatte heute ein interessantes Gespräch über die Verwendung von Leerzeichen bei [Auslassungspunkten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslassungspunkte) (…) innerhalb von Romanen.

Es geht um Sätze folgender Art

> Ich frage mich langsam… ob es richtig war… ob ich überhaupt das Richtige tue… Ich weiß es einfach nicht.

und ob man vor den Auslassungspunkten **immer** ein Leerzeichen setzen muss.

---

Vom Prinzip her sind die (verkürzt beschriebenen) Regeln klar:

- wird ein Wort nicht ausgeschrieben werden die Punkte direkt angehängt, z.B.

  > "So eine verf… Scheiße"
  >
  > "Ich bin nicht dei…", fing er an, bevor ich ihm mit einer Handbewegung das Wort abschnitt.
- Pausen oder Unterbrechungen werden durch drei Punkte mit Leerzeichen davor und danach dargestellt. Gedankenstriche wären theoretisch auch möglich, aber sind nicht Teil der Frage ;)

  > "Ich … kann nichts dazu sagen"
  >
  > Was macht dieser Mann nur mit mir? Warum … warum komme ich nicht von ihm los?

<sup>Für Auslassungen in Zitaten, Satzenden, etc. gibt es noch andere Regelungen, die hier aber unwichtig sind.</sup>

---

Nach meinem ästhetischem Geschmack stört das Leerzeichen vor dem Dreipunkt, wenn damit eine sprachliche oder gedankliche Pause angezeigt werden soll und es sich um einen Roman handelt. Es wirkt mehr wie ein Fremdkörper innerhalb des Satzes. Für mich wirkt es eher als würden Wörter wie in Zitaten […] fehlen, als eine Pause.

**Darum die Fragen:**

Muss man das Leerzeichen immer setzen oder kann ein Autor/in innerhalb eines Romans dichterische Freiheit nutzen und es ist immer noch "orthografisch richtig". Würde ein Lektor es immer korrigieren?

Wenn man es immer nutzen muss: Muss davor immer ein Viertelgeviert oder wäre auch ein schmales Leerzeichen, wie man es etwa bei "z. B." benutzen soll, möglich?

Das fehlende Leerzeichen wird oft als typischer Fehler genannt, kommt also häufig vor. Ist das Unwissen oder ist das die typische Verwendung in englischer Literatur? (Für die ich keine einheitlichen Regeln für den Dreipunkt, was Aussehen und Form angeht, finde)

Comment: Wofür steht das TLDR (too long didn't read?) am Anfang deiner Frage?

Comment: @harper Ja, es ist nicht der richtige Ausdruck für den Anfang, aber hab es mir woanders so angewöhnt ^^

Comment: Ich untersütze dich vollkommen in der Ansicht, dass es bescheuert aussähe, wenn man eine Gedankenunterbrechung... äh... mit einem Leerzeichen vor den drei Punkten notierte, auch wenn manche Rechtschreib- und Schriftsatzratzgeber dies so fordern. Nur wenn das Lehrz.... die drei Punkte direkt an den Vorgedanken anschließen, wird die spontante Unterbrechung sinnbildlich angezeigt.

Comment: @mtwde Die Frage nach der _künstlerischen Freiheit_ bezüglich des Textsatzes lässt mich an Ernst Jandl denken: `fr au` ... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Die meisten Regeln sind dazu da, das Lesen zu erleichtern.

Die Regeln selbst kennst Du ja und hast sie zitiert.

> "Sowas kann man sich nicht aus... "

könnte einen Abriss beim Wort "ausdenken" sein.

> "Sowas kann man sich nicht aus ... "

dagegen für "aus der Nase ziehen".

Künstlerische Freiheit kann man fast immer geltend machen, nicht nur in Romanen, und auch 2 Punkte verwenden um kürzere und 4 Punkte um längere Pausen zu markieren - nur wird es wegen mangelnder Standardisierung wahrscheinlich nicht verstanden und Lektoren werden es ebenfalls anstreichen. Individueller Wildwuchs verträgt sich ganz grundsätzlich nicht mit dem Bedürfnis, zu regeln, was orthographisch richtig ist.

Würde ich irgendwo einer falschen Setzung begegnen würde ich denken "schlampiges Korrektorat!" und auf Unkenntnis, nicht eine verborgene Absicht tippen. Gäbe es erläuterndes Vorwort würde ich denken: "Wenn man anders seine Individualität nicht ausdrücken kann ...".

Answer (score 3):

> Muss vor einen Auslassungsdreipunkt - … - , der eine Pause oder Unterbrechung anzeigt, immer ein (volles) Leerzeichen oder kann dichterische Freiheit darauf verzichten?

Ich würde ein Leerzeichen verwenden, wenn ich den Rest einer Phrase von Wörtern auslassen möchte wie in z.B.

> Ich sehe schon wohin das führt ...

In Fällen von nicht voll ausgesprochenen Wörtern wie in

> "So eine verf… Scheiße"
>
> "Ich bin nicht dei…", fing er an, bevor ich ihm mit einer Handbewegung das Wort abschnitt.

ist kein Leerzeichen erforderlich.